# Issues with Nested States in UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm having an issue with nested states in UI-Router. I have a two states, and upon button click it should transition to another state, and the url changes, but the template does not. Here is my code for the state logic:

```
$stateProvider.state('accounts', {
url: '/accounts',
views: {
  'menu': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'MenuController'
  },
  'main': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/accounts.html',
    controller: 'AccountsController'
  }
}
});
$stateProvider.state('accounts.detail', {
url: '/:accountID',
views: {
  'main': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/accounts.detail.html',
    controller: 'AccountsDetailController'
  }
}
});
```

And my button logic: `$state.go('accounts.detail', { accountID : account.accountID});`

Both of my views are wrapped up in ui-view tags. All other root states work correctly (/home, /orders) however /accounts/:accountID will not trigger the template to load and transition. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using jade? Show us the view

Comment: No, I am unsure of what that is. I am using ionic and that is my sole framework. It comes bundled with ui-router and angular

Comment: Sounds like the template of the `accounts` state is missing a `<ui-view />` tag, that would explain the route change but no template. What I'm unsure of though, is in which template (menu.html or accounts.html) you should define that ui-view tag in.

Comment: it's there, ion-view is the ionic equivalent: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Comment: added menu.html for clarity

Comment: If ion-view is the ionic equivalent of ui-view then it is being used incorrectly here. I do not know ionic at all. But if it is the same, that is not how you use it. It does not wrap around things.

Comment: I modified all of my code so it is only used once as a definition. same result.

Comment: codepen of ionic using ui-router effectively: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz?editors=101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I wasn't referring to my views correctly. Because of how they are nested, I needed to use the absolute name to cause the view to show. The linked UI-router documentation describes my issue.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names

Answer (score 1):

`<ion-view />` is not the equivalent of `<ui-view />`, in Ionic Framework it is just a container to insert header/footer bars and content.

use `<ion-nav-view />` http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/
and reference by name this nested view in your parent view: `<ion-nav-view name="main" />`